# The server at net.tcp://192.168.0.1:22/ServiceName/BufferedPoint rejected the session-establishment request

Tags: wcf, nettcpbinding

I have a service that uses WCF to talk to another service through a firewall on port 22.  The service has around 30 jobs that run every 5 seconds on a loop.  These jobs basically invoke the service on the client through the firewall (outgoing) and the first thing it does is checks against the config to see if its a valid job.  This setup is running on two pairs, for redundancy.

> server----->WCF----->client (pair 1)
>
> server----->WCF----->client (pair 2)

Whats happening in pair 2 is the exception in the title for some of the jobs that are being invoked by the server.  Restarting the service pair temporarily resolves this issue, but the errros start appearing once again as soon as the job is invoked and checked for validity against the client.  The check for validity is done for security so that only configured jobs can run on the client.  Its important to note that this is happening on some jobs only.

The log file on the server shows the times at which the service was invoked:

-[2011-10-24 12:35:43.726][INFO ] 8268 CL: www.foo.com: Starting new instance - j63454750613. Loop #877

-[2011-10-24 **12:35:43.726**][INFO ] 8268 CL: j63454750613: Checking server job validity...

-[2011-10-24 **12:35:43.742**][ERROR] 8268 CL: (evnt: 31975) j63454750613: ERROR: Synchronization failed with: Error while checking the server job: The server at net.tcp://192.168.0.1:22/ServiceName/BufferedPoint rejected the session-establishment request.

-[2011-10-24 **12:35:43.742**][INFO ] 8268 CL: j63454750613: Job is done.

Its important to note that the service invokation happens during the Checking job validity cycle, and that 16ms later the service throws an exception, but there is no record of the service being invoked in the client logs.

I've done some research and Microsoft techs say that the probable causes of this exception are the downlink being slow, the server being too busy, or port 818 being blocked.  In my case, the downlink is 100baseT, the server is a quad cpu 4g of ram barely breaking a sweat, and we use port 22.

Any ideas what could be happening here?  Id love to provide more details upon request.

Cheers.

Comment: What do you mean by "pair"? Does it mean that you have two services on client exposed on the same port? Why are you abusing port 22 which is reserved for other protocol? If you need such strange architecture opening port on firewall should be part of your application installation procedure.

Comment: Port 22 is the only port open on the infra, and this decision wasnt made by me.  There is a service sitting on each of the 4 servers, 2 clients, 2 "servers".  The services work perfectly on one set of servers but not on the backup; we have the described problem happening there.

Comment: The services i speak of are windows services someone wrote that run on the servers.  The services in the Intranet talk to the services on the DMZ through port 22 using WCF.

Answer (score 1):

192.168.1.1 is actually a non-public Internet Protocol Address that is placed to be the default IP through the creation of wireless routers. That is among the most often utilized default IPs at this time and also even though it is usually a factor of the router factory options, it is much not difficult to alter it depending on the user’s ease and comfort with the board of the modem. The truth is, it's also suggested to change it, if an individual has connections difficulties. Linksys modems are generally the most probably to possess 192.168.1.1 for their IP address.

Due to the fact [server 192.168.0.1](http://www.192-168-01.com/) is actually a non-public IP address, many find this specific Ip being utilized by various personal computers simultaneously, across the globe. Nevertheless, that is merely probable whenever the 2 machines implementing the identical Ip (192.168.1.1) operate at individual systems. However, when more than one computer systems are employing the IP Address 192.168.1.1 upon a one particular computer network, then there'd always be interaction concerns as well as the network system won't work as it must. It indicates that even though one could make use of the identical IP within a number of locations, only so long as these machines are not doing work with the identical system.